# MIT single variable calculus polar coordinate problem sheet questions

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I'm currently going through MIT's single variable calculus series, so far most the problem sheet questions are similar to the examples in the lecture, however I've just got to the polar coordinates section and I'm finding it difficult to apply what I've learned from the lectures to the problem set. I was wondering if anyone knows any resources I could use to help understand **4H-2** as I'm really at a loss how to solve these types of questions. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Problem sheet: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/unit-3-the-definite-integral-and-its-applications/part-a-definition-of-the-definite-integral-and-first-fundamental-theorem/problem-set-6/MIT18_01SC_pset4prb.pdf

Comment: Instead of providing a link to the entire sheet with a bajillion questions, it would be beneficial if you type out the _specific_ question you need help with (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) in your post.

Comment: I wrote section 4H-2 and was looking for resources for questions that are are of this type, not one particular question.

Comment: How far can you get in the problem?  Can you do part a), part b)?

Comment: I understood  a and b with the solutions, I didn't follow the solutions for c on wards